# GitHub Actions: workflow never ends

Tags: python, github-actions, tweepy

I have an application that is running endlessly on GitHub Action and every time I need to manually cancel the workflow.

My `main.yml` file is quite simple:

```yaml
#main.yml
name: Python Script Workflow

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "50 13 * * 1-5"

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    environment:
      name: production

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository content
        uses: actions/checkout@v2 # Checkout the repository content to github runner.

      - name: Setup Python Version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.9.6

      - name: Install Python dependencies
        uses: py-actions/py-dependency-install@v2
        with:
          path: "requirements.txt"

      - name: Run Python script # Run the app.py
        env:
          FROM_EMAIL: ${{ secrets.FROM_EMAIL }}
          FROM_PWD: ${{ secrets.FROM_PWD }}
          API_KEY: ${{ secrets.API_KEY }}
          API_KEY_SECRET: ${{ secrets.API_KEY_SECRET }}
          ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET }}
          BEARER_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.BEARER_TOKEN }}
        run: python app.py
```

I have an `app.py` that calls the file `read_email.py` which after reading calls the file below, this in turn performs the tweets. Here he is:

```py
#post_tweet.py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from os import getenv
from textwrap import wrap
from time import sleep
from tweepy import OAuthHandler, API


def twitter_connect(tweet_list):
    load_dotenv()
    consumer_key = getenv('API_KEY')
    consumer_secret = getenv('API_KEY_SECRET')
    access_token = getenv('ACCESS_TOKEN')
    access_token_secret = getenv('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET')

    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    api = API(auth)
    try:
        api.verify_credentials()
        post_tweet(tweet_list, api)
    except:
        sleep(120)
        twitter_connect(tweet_list)


def post_tweet(tweet_list, api):
    for tweet in tweet_list:
        print('\n' + tweet + '\n')
        each_tweet = wrap(tweet, 280, break_long_words=False)
        original_tweet = []
        for i, chunk in zip(range(len(each_tweet)), each_tweet):
            original_tweet.extend([chunk])
            print(original_tweet)
            if i == 0:
                original_tweet[i] = api.update_status(chunk)
            else:
                original_tweet[i] = api.update_status(chunk,
                                                      in_reply_to_status_id=original_tweet[i-1].id,
                                                      auto_populate_reply_metadata=True)
            sleep(1)
        sleep(300)
```

When I run it on localhost, it runs and finishes normally. But when it runs on GitHub Actions, after the last tweet, it doesn't finish as it should.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? What am I missing?

Last build: https://github.com/arnonrdp/Bot-Deschamps-Newsletter/actions/runs/1329254957

### EDIT:

```py
#read_email.py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from imap_tools import MailBox, MailMessageFlags, A
from os import getenv
from post_tweet import twitter_connect
from time import sleep


def mail_connect():
    load_dotenv()
    FROM_EMAIL = getenv('FROM_EMAIL')
    FROM_PWD = getenv('FROM_PWD')
    SMTP_SERVER = "imap.gmail.com"

    mailbox = MailBox(SMTP_SERVER).login(
        FROM_EMAIL, FROM_PWD, initial_folder='INBOX')
    read_email(mailbox)


def read_email(mailbox):
    posts = []
    mail_list = [i.uid for i in mailbox.fetch()]
    if mail_list:
        for msg in mailbox.fetch(A(from_='newsletter@filipedeschamps.com.br')):
            posts = msg.text.replace('*', '').split('\r\n\r\n')
            posts = posts[2:-3]
            mark_as_read(mailbox)
            archive_message(mailbox, msg.uid)
        twitter_connect(posts)
    else:
        sleep(60)
        mail_connect()


def mark_as_read(mailbox):
    flags = (MailMessageFlags.ANSWERED, MailMessageFlags.FLAGGED)
    mailbox.flag(mailbox.fetch(A(seen=False)), flags, True)
    mailbox.flag(mailbox.fetch("SENTON 01-Jan-2021"),
                 MailMessageFlags.SEEN, False)


def archive_message(mailbox, msg_uid):
    move_to = 'Tweeted'
    mailbox.move(msg_uid, move_to)
```

Comment: The workflow implementation on Github Actions looks ok, so I guess it's related to your script execution. Since your [last commit](https://github.com/arnonrdp/Bot-Deschamps-Newsletter/commit/16acbcc156969a777423a86d8bc5fc69fe5612cb) it seems to read the same mail in loop (as the text you extract appears many time in the workflow execution). I would first verify why the loop isn't ending on the runner as you observed locally (it's not easy to reproduce without your credentials).

Comment: Here's what happens: every day at 1pm I receive a newsletter and the application only reads this email (`msg`). But this newsletter contains several news. I share these news in a list (`posts`). So I mark the email as read, file this incoming email and then call `post_tweet`. Really, without the credentials it's difficult, I don't know how to get around it.

Comment: The scenario that might be happening is that your call the mail_connect() many times in loop instead of only once when you run it on the runner. Could it be related to the mailbox.fetch() or the mark_as_read() methods ?

Comment: This really makes a lot of sense. The ideal really is that I only call once. I'm going to make this modification and try to run workflow again. Later I bring the result here. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've calmly analyzed the for loop and believe that it can't be the problem. Because if the `twitter_connect` function was called that means the for loop is over. On the other hand, in order not to need to call WorkFlow several times I used an `else` in `read_email.py` and an `except` in `post_tweet.py` for the function to call itself if the connection fails. I wonder if she's somehow in an infinite loop because of that.

Comment: The loop may be due to this `expect`. Did you try removing it to check how the workflow behaves on Github Actions?